# Issue with dynamic and text placement

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is when I click the submit button it puts all the name and first name in large text into the div contactcard1 , when they click see description it switches to contactcard2, I need the info for description to show in contactcard2,  as well as every time the info gets submitted on the left it makes a new box dynamically on the page that does the same as the contact 1 and 2 box.  I have got most of this working but can't seem to get those functions working. I did get document.on turned on so i can use the features. But would appropriate any help in getting this fixed.

My HTML

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">


           $(document).ready(function() {
      var table = $('#tabletop');
      $('.button').click(function() {
        var row = tabletop.insertRow();
        ['1stname', '2ndname', '3rdname', '4thname'].forEach(function(elementId) {
          var cell = row.insertCell();
          cell.innerHTML = document.getElementById(elementId).value;
        });
      });
    });

         function switchVisible() {
    if (document.getElementById('contactcard1') !== undefined) {

        if (document.getElementById('contactcard1').style.display == 'block') {
            document.getElementById('contactcard1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('contactcard2').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('contactcard1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('contactcard2').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}

         $('button').append('#maindiv')
        $(document).on()

  </script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id='wrapper'>
       <div id='container1'></div>

      <div id=maindiv>
       <div id='container2'>

            <form id='form1'>
               First name:<br>
               <input id='1stname' type="text" name="firstname" value="First Name">
               <br> Last name:<br>
               <input id='2ndname' type="text" name="lastname" value="Last Name">
               <br> Description:<br>
               <input id='3rdname' type="text" name="description" value="Description">


            </form>

              <button class='button'>Submit</button>
       </div>
       <div id='container3'>  
         <div id='contactcard1'>
          <table id='tabletop'>
            <tr>
              <th id='first'>First Name</th>
              <th id='last'>Last Name</th>
              <input id="Button1" type="button" value="See My Description" onclick="javascript:switchVisible();" />



            </tr>
          </table>
          </div>  


        <div id='contactcard2'>
          <table id='tabletop1'>
            <tr>

              <th id='description'>Description</th>

            </tr>
          </table>
          </div>
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>


MY CSS

*

#wrapper{

    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black ;
}

#container1{

    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black ;
}

#container2{

    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black ;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#container3{

    width: 580px;
    height: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black ;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#form1{

    margin-top: 100px;
}

#contactcard1{

    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 100px;

}
#contactcard2{

    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 100px;

}

#button1{

    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of thing you need to do here.
I created a fiddle for you as a working version. Take a look and let me know if you don't understand.
https://jsfiddle.net/0433Lo2u/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
document.getElementById('contactcard1').style.display = 'block';

      $('.button').click(function() {
      var row = undefined;
      if (document.getElementById('contactcard1').style.display == 'block') {

        row = tabletop.insertRow();
      }else{

        row = tabletop1.insertRow();
      }
        ['1stname', '2ndname', '3rdname'].forEach(function(elementId) {
          var cell = row.insertCell();
          cell.innerHTML = document.getElementById(elementId).value;
        });
      });

$('#Button1').click(function(){
    if (document.getElementById('contactcard1') !== undefined) {

        if (document.getElementById('contactcard1').style.display == 'block') {
            document.getElementById('contactcard1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('contactcard2').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('contactcard1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('contactcard2').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
})
    });
```

Comment: You didn't link the jsfiddle

Comment: Try to click through buttons, your code is not working when you click `description` button

Comment: I see you cleaned my code up a ton I thank you could you point me in the right direction to fix the rest. Yea i am still working on getting the text to second box for discription.  As far as clicking it to view. Yea just tested it does work

Comment: It's already working as you expected in the original question. What do you want to fix here?

Comment: No Im trying to get the submit button to clone the box and function on the right and append new boxes with the info. ANd I need to move the form description to the 2 contact card.